# Loading pre trained word2vec model in convolution neural network classifier

Tags: python, word2vec

Is it possible to load pre trained word2vec model file in a classifier for classification task?

Comment: Everything's possible if you write the code yourself. And it might be possible with other libraries/components as well – depending on which code you're using, and what you're trying to achieve. You'll have to be more specific.